# Avoiding repetition in Interface contract classes

Tags: c#, dry, code-contracts

We want to use code contracts on our interfaces. We have a large interface hierarchy, leading to an awful lot of duplication in the contract classes.

We have an interface `IX` which (through inheriting from other interfaces) has around 50 methods. There are several interfaces that derive from `IX`. Interface `IY` inherits from `IX`, adding only a couple of methods. If I want to add a contract class for `IY`, I need to reference all 50+ methods. Worse, if later on I decide to modify `IX`, I have to change all the contract classes for all interfaces inheriting from `IX`. This discourages developers from making changes.

Is there a way of avoiding this duplication?

Comment: too much text. No code. Post the relevant code. I'm too lazy to read all that.

Comment: You can try inheriting contract classes

Comment: You have interfaces with 50 methods and still interested in keeping code clean..

Comment: @lazyb: Our interface/class hierarchy is admittedly a bit out of control, but no single interface introduces very many new methods over its base interface(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, no. You can't derive one interface contract class from another, and interface contracts classes can't have any base class other than System.Object. So I think you're stuck. Your best way forwards would probably involve some kind of code generation tool, or lots of copy-and-pasting.

Comment: That's what I figured (though wasn't sure). I've been meaning to look at T4 for a while - maybe now's the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem with some code I have been writing although not quite on the same scale. My solution has been to use the IDE/ReSharper to just add the `NotImplementedException` stubs for new methods or write them as `abstract override`. All contracts defined in the base class should be in stone at that point as the CC tools will yell at you if you attempt to add `Contract.Requires` to them in the contract class for `IY` for example.